# Should "Belongs on X" be pulled up the list of close reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just saw a question closed as "not programming related" but it really belonged on superuser.com.

Would putting the "Belongs on X" close reasons at the top of the list encourage people to use them instead of a generic "not programming related" option?

Comment: Hell no! In most cases this will mean they also migrate questions that don't belong on SU either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've said before, I don't use the SF and SU sites so I have no means of knowing what is appropriate there. I therefore close non-programming questions as NPR. Given the grumbles from SF and SU mods about their sites being used as a dumping ground, I think this is the right thing to do, and I would in fact argue for the complete removal of the ability to transfer questions **except** for users who have the ability to transfer them back - i.e. you must have over 3000 rep on both ends of the transfer.

Comment: Unfortunately the "transfer them back" bit doesn't work - it needs a diamond mod to do that.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm not so worried that it is actually possible, only that they heave the required rep at both ends i.e. they some idea whatis on-topic for both sites.

Comment: @Neil - interesting idea - might it be worth filing it as a separate question?

Comment: Personally I don't have a big issue with questions that get transfered to SO, that say should be on SU, what I have a problem with is where people transfer questions that are obviously bad, its not that they are not just suited to SO, they are not suited to be answered at all! With valid questions, that deserve an answer, i've no problem moving them on again to SU if needed.